# php date re-arrange to mysql do i need to use explode?

Tags: php, date

i have question, i am using PHP script, there is something wrong when i add date to my database...

how can i fix/re-arrange this date

`date( "Oct 18, 2012 05:06:42" );`

my database accept only `2012-10-19 05:06:42`

but i am receiving different form which is this `Oct 18, 2012 05:06:42`

here are my example code

```
$cocod = date( 'Oct 18, 2012 05:06:42' );//'Oct 18, 2012 2012-10-18';
$get = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:m:s", strtotime($cocod)) . " +30 day");
$setex = date( 'Y-m-d H:m:s', $get );
echo $setex;
```

thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your formatted date back to a timestamp using the DateTime class

```
$timestamp = DateTime::createFromFormat('M d, Y H:i:s', 'Oct 18, 2012 05:06:42')->getTimestamp();
```

In your example above i can see you even wanted to add 30 days. You could do that like this:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('M d, Y H:i:s', 'Oct 18, 2012 05:06:42');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P30D'));
```

If you now want to format your date again, do the following:

```
$date->format('Y-m-d H:m:s');
```

For further reading take a look at the [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class on php.net

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
$cocod = 'Oct 18, 2012 05:06:42'; // original date

$get = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($cocod . " +30 days"));

echo $get;
```

**Outputs**

> 2012-11-17 05:06:42

Answer (score 0):

The long hand way...

```
$d0 = explode(",", $date);

$d1 = explode(" ", $d0[0]);

$d2 = explode(" ", trim($d0[1]));


$year = $d2[0];
$month = monthToInt($d1[0]);
$day = $d1[1];
$time = $d2[1];


$mysql_date = $year . "-" . $month . "-" . $day . "" . $time;
```

The `monthToInt` function is just one that takes "`Oct`" and turns it to `10`. You can write that yourself quite easily with 12 `if statements` or a `switch statement`, or find one pre-made on the internet.